# Unison: Ignore all files with *.ext, except those in a specific subdirectory

Tags: unison

I am trying to perform a sync using Unison (2.40.102) where I want to ignore all files with a specific extension, say `*.ext`, but not ignore the files with this extension if they are in a specific subfolder.

Folder structure:

```
main_dir
|file.ext
|...
|--sub_dir_1
   |more_files.ext
   |...
|--sub_dir_2
   |even_more_files.ext
   |...
   |--dir_I_want_to_sync
      |sync_this_file1.ext
      |...
      |sync_this_fileN.ext
      |--some_arbitrarily_named_dir
         |also_sync_this.ext
         |...
         |--more_arbitrarily_named_dirs_with_ext_files_in_them
            |...
```

As the folder structure is not constant, I cannot just ignore only specific paths, but have to do this very generally. My idea was to first ignore all the files with the extension `*.ext` and then *un-ignore* the ones below `dir_I_want_to_sync`.
However, that is were I am failing to find the right command...

The relevant parts of my profile file look like this:

```
# Ignore all files with extension *.ext
ignore = Name {.,}*{.ext}

# Try to not ignore the files within the subdirectory (NOT WORKING)
ignorenot = Path */dir_I_want_to_sync/*             # 1)
ignorenot = Name */dir_I_want_to_sync/{*/}*{.ext}   # 2)
```

Remarks:
1) Does not do anything, because the files are ignored by their file**name**, not their path
2) Was meant to reverse the ignore on all the files in `dir_I_want_to_sync`, but it does not catch all subfolders.

Is there any way to apply the `ignorenot = Name ...` to a file regardless of how deep it is in the directory structure, as long as it is below a directory with a specific name?

(I hope, this was not too confusing. I am happy to clarify!)

Comment: Try `ignorenot = Regex */dir_I_want_to_sync/.*\.ext`. Please let me know if this works.

Comment: Or potentially better, try `ignorenot = BelowPath full/path/to/the/dir_I_want_to_sync/with/ext/files/underneath/{.*,*}.ext`. Note that in a `Path` the `*` matches any string of characters *except* the `/` character, so you can't use it to represent arbitrary paths.

Comment: @mapierce271 Ah, so that's why `2)`did not work! Thanks for your note. In the `Regex` it seems like the initial `.` is missing, right? – compare to @Gilles answer. Unfortunately, I could not get the `BelowPath` to work, although it seems like a handy option as well! But the Regex did the job, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Regex` instead of `Path` when you need to match an arbitrary directory depth.

```
ignore = Name *.ext
ignorenot = Regex .*/dir_I_want_to_sync/.*\.ext
```